Taxonerd Set-up
I am trying to get taxonerd to work. I had an issue initially with nmslib when trying to download this module. I created a new virtual environment and downgraded the python within that environment to 3.8.5. I was able to pip install the taxonerd module into this environment. However, when I try to rune the following code in jupyter notebook:
import pandas
import numpy
from taxonerd import TaxoNERD

I get the following error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 3
      1 import pandas
      2 import numpy
----> 3 from taxonerd import TaxoNERD

File ~\.conda\envs\py38\lib\site-packages\taxonerd\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from .taxonerd import TaxoNERD
      2 from .cli import *
      4 __version__ = "1.5.2"

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'taxonerd.taxonerd'

What am I doing wrong?
update: I have restarted my computer since the installation and I have also restarted the kernel and I still get this error.

Just restart the Jupyter Notebook and try to import one more time...Maybe its caching issue..

I still get this error even with a full PC reset. I have also restarted the python kernel for the jupyter notebook to no avail.

@Wayne I have tried to install the package via the '%pip install taxonerd' from the jupyter notebook itself, I can see from the '%pip list' command that it is set up as a module in this environment. This would be the first time that a module has set up incorrectly for me in this way. I can see from the taxonerd repository on GitHub that this is how the init.py file is set up with the lines 'from .taxonerd import TaxonNERD' and 'from .cli import *'.

That definitely looks like a bad install then if the __init__.py of the package itself is triggering that. I would suggest making a new conda environment and installing again. If that shows the same issue....FWIW, it is a complex install yet works if you go here and do launch binder and then open a terminal and run pip install taxonerd in the terminal there. Then in a notebook the import works using from taxonerd import TaxoNERD. Maybe seeing something in how it installs will spark an idea for you in what could have gone wrong.

I have attempted a fresh install from another virtual environment and I can see that one of the folders "taxonerd" within the  "sitepackages" folder is missing several .py files. This would explain why the module cannot find taxonerd.taxonerd. However, when I try and manually import them I get a series of other problems cropping up with the install.
